# How to use FocusTraversalPolicy with MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, focus, miglayout

I have a `JPanel` with components added with absolute locations (ie. "pos x y"), and the layout is effectively two columns of textfields. What I would like to achieve would be for *Tab* to shift the focus to the next component vertically, so as to traverse the first column, then the second. At the moment it does it horizontally. I've tried to extend `FocusTraversalPolicy` but what annoyed me was that you have to add it to the `JFrame` and not just the panel itself - unless that's incorrect?

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the default focus traversal cycle is the natural order of the childcomponents in a container, i.e. the order in which they were added to the container. I don't know MigLayout very well, but if you manage to add the components vertically, the focus traversal might follow.

You can set a FocusTraversalPolicy to any Container, however, Swing will only use it when you call setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true) on the same Container.

Comment: `MigLayout` seems to determine the order based on the position of the components, maybe because I added them with absolute values. The second part of your answer was exactly what I was looking for though. Thanks. :)